# Is there a way to add an attribute to a text node in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, text, textnode

I want to add an attribute to a text node so that I can uniquely identify it. Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: You could identify it by a) logging a reference to it in a var; b) noting its index amongst its siblings (granted b is not an option if you're moving elements around). Otherwise, as @Matt Ball says in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in a safe, simple, cross-browser way. Only tags have attributes, and text nodes are not tags.
Wrap it in a `<span>` and use an ID on the span.